# Open Source viewer Like ArcReader

Tags: open-source-gis, arcreader

I would like to know if their are any open source map desktop based map viewers something similar to ArcReader. Preferably if this can use the files created from QGIS.

Comment: Why does QGIS not qualify as a viewer? You can hide the "confusing" toolbars.

Comment: What if I make a map and want to distribute it to people and want them to just view ,zoom and identify. QGIS would be a complete GIS package which would not be preferred.

Comment: Only QGIS can open QGIS project files. (The same is true for other open source GIS.) You will not want to distribute separate data files I think. The usual solution is to create an web viewer instead, so people don't have to install anything on their machines.

Comment: I don't think it qualifies as Open Source but Gaia from The Carbon Project may be a good fit for your requirements.  It can be downloaded from http://www.thecarbonproject.com/gaia.php

Comment: @underdark yes the main idea was of no distribution of data. Web viewer was another solution but for instant use I was looking to some desktop based solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ArcGIS Explorer Online](http://www.arcgis.com/explorer/) to create a free GIS web map.  I believe you just have to create a global account with ESRI.

Comment: I can use arcgis.com or arcgis explorer online in case to upload my shapfiles and that too would be restricted to just 1000 features. If I have data more than that I am stuck. What would be a more suitable desktop client as of now?

Comment: @Senthil, I'm not sure if you have ArcGIS, if you do you could export out data as a Geo-PDF with layers and attributes.

Comment: I dont have arcgis , but do you have any idea if I can export Geo-PDF layers with any open source GIS desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This reads shapefiles and is configurable.

http://www.mapwindow.org/